# How to add the dropdown menu in ActionMode's contextual menu

Tags: android-actionmode

I want to add a dropdown menu in ActionMode which looks like the one in Android's official Gallery app,  it allows you to 'select all' or 'deselect all' images. As seen in the picture below:
[image]

The only way I found is using custom view by calling [setCustomView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html#setCustomView%28android.view.View%29) and doing all the other stuffs by myself.  But I believe there must be some native method to enable this feature, can any one give any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I got it finally. The drop down menu is added by calling `setCustomView`, it replaced the default TextView.

I thought that method would replace the whole ActionMode view, what a low-level mistake.

Comment: 你好！It would be nice if you could show some sample code :)

Comment: @phantomlimb you can refer to this, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/jb-dev/src/com/android/gallery3d/ui/ActionModeHandler.java. Look at the method `startActionMode()`

Comment: @MehulJoisar the Gallery's source code is the working code, mine is similar to that.